# Marshalling C# array of enums to be modified in c++ Code

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling

I have a pre-built C++ API that takes a pointer to an array of enums as an output parameter and the length of the array, and returns the number of values modified. The function's purpose is to set values in the array to be used later. I'm trying to call this function from C# code, which includes its own version of the enum.

The C++ function signature looks like:

```
static int DoAThing(SomeEnum outArray[], int length)
```

and my C# function call currently looks like this:

```
[DLLImport("API.dll", EntryPoint="DoAThing")]
public static extern int DoAThing([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U4, SizeParamIndex = 1)]ref WrappedEnum[] outArray, int length);
```

My calling code looks like:

```
int length = 10;
WrappedEnum[] outArray = new WrappedEnum[length];
DoAThing(ref outArray, length);
```

I'm able to call into the function just fine, but I keep getting a NullReferenceException whenever it tries to return back to managed code with no useful callstack or information. I've also tried wrapped outArray in a GCHandle using GCHandle.Alloc with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Lots of questions about this already.  You forgot to use the CallingConvention property in your [DllImport] declaration, it is Cdecl.

Comment: Actually, according to the documentation the CallingConvention is not strictly necessary. The .NET runtime will use a default value, which works fine for my case.

Comment: Then you'll need to post a proper C++ declaration for the function.  As given, this will always be compiled to a __cdecl function unless non-standard compile options are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working. Some of these steps may be unnecessary, but they don't seem to hurt:

I added a SecurityPermission attribute to the top of the function:

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
```

and wrapped the calling code itself with a fixed block:

```
fixed (WrapperEnum* ptr_to_enum = &outArray[0]) { DoAThing(ref outArray, length); }
```

I also, wrapped the enum array in a GCHandle using GCHandle.Alloc and free'd it after the call to ensure it gets cleaned up properly.